# video plug-in for moodle

Tags: php, moodle, plugins

currently the moodle that we are using doesn't have a video plug-in.i have developed a video plug-in for moodle.I would like to add the plug-in  to the Moodle software that is being used in our institution.I am new to open source. How to include the plug-in .how do i go about with the integration ,so that i am able to use the video plug-in next time i use moodle.the plug-in has been written in php

Answer (score 2):

Here is Moodle's official Documentation for developing a **new Module**:
http://docs.moodle.org/en/newmodule

start with the suggested **template** (download.moodle.org/plugins19/mod/NEWMODULE.zip) to wrap your code with.

You can always look inside **Kaltura.com**'s video plugin code (http://www.kaltura.org/kaltura-moodle-plugin-installation-guide) and see how video can be implemented into Moodle. in general.

Answer (score 1):

Installing plugins into moodle is as simple as copying them to the /mod/ directory. SQL tables will be written and updated.

Then you should be able to see this module on the next login.

EDIT:

Check if the permissions for that folder and files are correct. Check if the file version.php exists and is correct (check other modules to see how its done). Check if the directory structure is correct also.

If all else fails, I would check out some other modules that are similar to yours and mimic their setup procedure

EDIT 2:

There's not much more i can assist you with. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the help.
we tried exactlty what you suggested,but it didnt work out .this is the response that we are getting...

Module devtp: C:\wamp\www\moodle/mod/devtp/version.php was not readable

where,'devtp' is the name of the plug-in directory that we would like to add.

do you think we have missed out on including any related files for our plug-in or is it bcoz we need to include some files that can make the plug-in COMPATIBLE with the current version of MOODLE. Our Moodle VERSION is 1.9.

Awaiting your response.

Answer (score 0):

we now included the version.php file and thus the error 
"Module devtp: C:\wamp\www\moodle/mod/devtp/version.php was not readable" is no longer coming. thank you for the help.
But still,our module has not been included under notifications in Moodle.We consulted the MOODLE site for help,
"http://docs.moodle.org/en/Installing_contributed_modules_or_plugins"
and followed the instruction:
// Visit your Local Moodle site http://localhost:8888/moodle19/

Site Administration
  Notifications
   Scroll to the bottom of the page and click on "Continue"//

but the fact is that ,neither is our module appearing under notifications and nor is continue coming.

Awaiting your response...

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to add video to a moodle course (if you dont want to create or invest in plugin) is to create a new 'page' type resource in moodle course.

In HTML code of that page add code for embedding a video. 
Video can be hosted on youtube or your own CDN. For own CDN you may have to use video.js